Swift Date relationship, deleted object after after reopen app
i have issue with objects.I have models
@Model
class Tag {
    
    var id: UUID
    var title: String = ""
    var color: Int = 0xFFFFFF

   
    init( title: String, color: Int ) {
        self.id  = UUID()
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
       
    }
    
}
@Model
class Task {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String = ""
    var tags: [Tags] = []
    
    init(title: String, tags: [Tags] = [] ) {
        self.title = title
        self.tags = tags
    }
}

i select tags before create task with  @State private var selectedTags: [Tags] = []than i create task with tags
let newTask = Task(
    title: taskTitle,
    tags: allTags
  
)

selectedList!.tasks.append(newTask)
try? modelContext.save()

when I create several tasks with the same tag, at first everything is fine, but if I reload the application, the tag remains in the last added task and all other tags are deleted.I don’t understand why the same tag can’t be in several tasks.

Note, @Model class ... already includes a id. There is no need for adding another var id. Also Swift already has a Task struct, change the name of yours to avoid confusing yourself and the compiler.

I think you just need to call modelContext.insert(Task) before the save operation.
